# Where in/near London does a giant electric tee hang off the ceiling as a piece of art?

Tags: uk, london, power, museums

In some museum of London or its vicinity, there was (and perhaps still is) an enormous electric tee (also known as three-way electric plug, multiplug outlet/power extender, cube tap, …) in a dark color (probably, brown) hanging off the ceiling with pins showing down.  It looked very similar to [Giant 3-Way Plug Scale 2/3](https://www.tate.org.uk/art/artworks/oldenburg-giant-3-way-plug-scale-2-3-t01266), except it could have been darker and was (and perhaps still is) ***not*** in the Hagia Sophia mosque in Istanbul. The plug is not distorted in any obvious way (but only scaled). Any more details about this piece of art? Where in/near London is it exactly?

Comment: Your link indicates the Tate Gallery, and that other sizes and materials were made. You can find details of Claes Oldenberg exhibitions which include *Giant Three-Way Plug* [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_public_art_by_Oldenburg_and_van_Bruggen)

Comment: @WeatherVane, that looks like an answer, please post as such.

Comment: @Willeke I don't think it's a good answer. AlMa1r, **your own link** is for the Tate's exhibit (London), and it says the artists made several in different sizes and materials. Two more are located in US as listed in my earlier link.

Comment: @WeatherVane Though the Website I linked is Tate, the text given on that Web site says that the item was in Istanbul on Feb 2011. Do they move the Big Plug around the world?

Comment: I think you are misreading it. It *isn't* in Hagia Sophia mosque in Istanbul as you wrote, but says it was *inpsired* by its hanging lights. "*This suspended, mahogany version was associated by the artist with the hanging lights inside the Hagia Sophia mosque in Istanbul.*" means the lights were hanging there, not the art work.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh my gosh, thank you; I really misread the text.

Answer (score 5):

[This Flickr picture](https://www.flickr.com/photos/4rosesynaranja/6437275051/) claims to show the sculpture at the Tate Modern in London 12 years ago. What is on display there changes regularly though and the link you included in your post says the one in the Tate collection is not on display currently (presumably in storage or on loan to another gallery around the world). A few Google searches doesn't come up with any others in London recently